# Partial Export of typescript modules in a namespace

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a simplified API surface that brings a bunch of typescript modules together (i.e., `let asdf = new Root.A.B.C()`).

I would like to split up some imports into namespaces. I'm not sure if typescript supports this, I'm hoping it does. Something similar to this...

```
import { C, default as D } from './ModuleA';
import * as B from './ModuleB';

export namespace A {
  export { C, D };
};

export { B };
```

`ModuleB` is namespaced because I'm exporting everything under as the alias `B`, but I cannot do a partial export of `ModuleA` because you cannot exportinside of a namespace.

Hopefully I'm just missing something obvious and simple.

Thanks.

Comment: Minor : unconventional to have semicolon in `namespace Foo{}` like unconventional in `if(){};` or `function(){};` or `class Foo{};`. Does no harm but even semicolon lovers (like myself) don't write a semicolon there 

Comment: i agree it looks strange, but in the case of an export, the AST is actually parsed as a statement (i assume) which by nature ends with a semi. I'm mildly curious how tslint handles that...

Comment: I was (randomly) reading the grammar spec and noticed that not all exports are statements, and namespace exports among others definitely do not parse the semi. so i will agree that a semi following a namespace export is certainly unconventional :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm hoping it does.

It does. However your `export` syntax in `export {/*something*/}` is wrong. It needs to be `export something = somethingElse`. E.g.

```
import { C as importedC} from './ModuleA';
export namespace A {
  export const C = importedC;
}
```

Comment: I just came to the same answer a few mins ago too. I struggled further on how to export interfaces (and by extension other types) but figured that out as well. I'll mark your answer accepted and add my own additional info answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add onto the accepted answer, here is a demo of how to export a generic interface, a class type, a class variable (new-able), an instance, and a function into a sub-namespace from an imported module. Note that we are selecting individual exports from `ModuleA` to export into our `A` namespace.

```
import * as AExports from './ModuleA';

export namespace A {
  export type IGenericInterface<T> = AExports.IGenericInterface<T>;
  export type SomeClass = AExports.SomeClass;
  export var SomeClass = AExports.SomeClass;
  export const Instance = AExports.default;
  export const someFunction = AExports.someFunction;
}
```

You can actually save a few key strokes by using an `import alias` which will export both the type and variable declarations in one line.

```
import * as AExports from './ModuleA';

export namespace A {
  export import IGenericInterface = AExports.IGenericInterface;
  export import SomeClass = AExports.SomeClass;
  export const Instance = AExports.default;
  export const someFunction = AExports.someFunction;
}
```

When dealing with module augmentation, import aliases are the only way to accomplish this.

```
import * as AExports from './ModuleA';
import * as B from 'ModuleB';

declare module 'ModuleB' {
  namespace Things {
    export namespace A {
      export import SomeClass = AExports.SomeClass;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your export for `SomeClass` will not allow users to do `new SomeClass`. Have a look at https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html for ways around that 

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will update this answer with a more complete answer.